# want to php array results listed left to right

Tags: php, arrays

This is a basic question, but I cannot find the answer anywhere. I want to list my php array results from left to right, then when reach the end of the row, start a new row. like this:

1     2     3     4

5     6     7

Seems simple but is driving me nuts. Cannot do it with tables, tried with css div to no avail.

Here is my code on the page that I want for each result:

```
 <?php 
if ($this->meeting){
?><?php
foreach($this->meeting as $meet){
echo date_bl($meet->date,$meet->time);
echo '<br />';
echo $meet->place;
echo '<br />';
echo $meet->address;
echo '<br />';
echo $meet->city.", ".$meet->state." ".$meet->zip;
echo '<br />';
}}else{}?>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Could you show us the bit of code you're struggling with?

Comment: how do you know when you hit the end of the row or how many columns there should be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### PHP

```
<?php 
if($this->meeting){
 echo '<ul class="list">';
 foreach($this->meeting as $meet){
  echo '<li>';
  echo date_bl($meet->date,$meet->time);
  echo '<br />';
  echo $meet->place;
  echo '<br />';
  echo $meet->address;
  echo '<br />';
  echo $meet->city.", ".$meet->state." ".$meet->zip;
  echo '<br />';
  echo '</li>';
 }
 echo '</ul>';
} else {

}
?>
```

### CSS

```
.list {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 list-style:none;
}
.list li {
 width:200px;
 display:inline-block;
 padding:5px 9px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even simpler:

```
<p><?php echo implode(' ', $array); ?></p>
```

Without knowing the structure of your array this is the simplest thing I can provide.

Comment: It is, just think of each of the numbers as a box/variable, rather than a literal number.